# How to pass images from drawable in intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-drawable

I am trying to pass images from drawable in intent but not able to do

Sender Activity:

```java
public class ShowSquadAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ShowSquadAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context con;
    Bitmap bmp,bmp1,bmp2,bmp3,bmp4,bmp5,bmp6,bmp7,bmp8,bmp9,bmp10,bmp11,bmp12,bmp13,bmp14,bmp15;
    public ArrayList<SquadModel> squad=new ArrayList<SquadModel>();

    public ShowSquadAdapter(Context con,ArrayList<SquadModel> data)
    {
        this.con=con;
        this.squad=data;

    }
    @Override
    public ShowSquadAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(con).inflate(R.layout.card_squad,parent,false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(view);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ShowSquadAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final SquadModel squadModel = squad.get(position);
        if(holder==null) {
            Log.e("tag","null");
        }

        ImageView imageView=holder.imvplayer;
      imageView.setImageResource(squadModel.getIconid());
        if(holder.equals(null))
        {
            Log.e("tag","null");
        }
        TextView textView = holder.tvplayername;
        textView.setText(squadModel.getName());
        holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
 Intent j = new Intent(con,ShowSquad.class);
j.putExtra("Juan Calatayud",squadModel.getIconid());
                Log.e("tag", String.valueOf(squadModel.getIconid()));
                j.putExtra("Amrinder Singh",squadModel.getIconid());
                j.putExtra("Kunzang Bhutia",squadModel.getIconid());
                j.putExtra("Nallappan Mohanraj",squadModel.getIconid());
                j.putExtra("Arnab Mondal",squadModel.getIconid());
                j.putExtra("Denzil Franco",squadModel.getIconid());
                j.putExtra("Syed Rahim Nabi",squadModel.getIconid());
                j.putExtra("Rino Anto",squadModel.getIconid());
                j.putExtra("Augustin Fernandes",squadModel.getIconid());
                j.putExtra("Jaime Gavilán",squadModel.getIconid());
                j.putExtra("Borja Fernández",squadModel.getIconid());
                j.putExtra("Clifford Miranda",squadModel.getIconid());
                j.putExtra("Arata Izumi",squadModel.getIconid());
                j.putExtra("Sameehg Doutie",squadModel.getIconid());
                j.putExtra("Ofentse Nato",squadModel.getIconid());
                j.putExtra("Jorge Alonso",squadModel.getIconid());
```

Receiver Activity:

```java
public class ShowSquad extends AppCompatActivity {
    public ArrayList<SquadModel> squad=new ArrayList<SquadModel>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_showsquad);
        imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imvshowsquad);
        textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvshow);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        //SquadModel squadModel = squad.
        if(bundle!=null) {

            byte arr[] = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("Juan Calatayud");
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arr,0,arr.length);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                //SquadModel squadModel = squad.get(i);
                imageView.setImageResource(bundle.getInt("Juan Calatayud",R.drawable.p_juan));
                imageView.setImageResource(bundle.getInt("Amrinder Singh"));
                imageView.setImageResource(bundle.getInt("Kunzang Bhutia"));
                imageView.setImageResource(bundle.getInt("Nallappan Mohanraj"));
                imageView.setImageResource(bundle.getInt("Arnab Mondal"));
                imageView.setImageResource(bundle.getInt("Denzil Franco"));
                imageView.setImageResource(bundle.getInt("Syed Rahim Nabi"));
                imageView.setImageResource(bundle.getInt("Rino Anto"));
                imageView.setImageResource(bundle.getInt("Augustin Fernandes"));
                imageView.setImageResource(bundle.getInt("Jaime Gavilán"));
                imageView.setImageResource(bundle.getInt("Borja Fernández"));
                imageView.setImageResource(bundle.getInt("Clifford Miranda"));
                imageView.setImageResource(bundle.getInt("Arata Izumi"));
                imageView.setImageResource(bundle.getInt("Sameehg Doutie"));
                imageView.setImageResource(bundle.getInt("Ofentse Nato"));
                imageView.setImageResource(bundle.getInt("Jorge Alonso"));
```

Comment: Please format your code!

Comment: you can able to send bitmap in intent but don't do it. You will run into out of memory error. instead save the image to local app folder and send only the path of the image with intent.

Answer (score 0):

Create array of

```
int[] drawables = {R.drawables.image,R.drawables.image2,R.drawables.image3};
```

and pass it or simply pass

```
int drawable  = R.drawable.image;
```